# fadeIn not working after AJAX .load call

Tags: jquery

I've created a callback function to hide the .calorie-table div then fadein a div after an item is added to my basket, however, only the hide part is working.  The fadeIn seems to be completely ignored.

Can anybody advise please?

here is code:

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
          url: "../ajax/add-ingredient-to-recipe.php?"+dataString,  
          dataType: "html",
          data: dataString,  
          success: function (msg) {

            frames.top.$.fancybox.close(true);                
            frames.top.$('.calorie-table').load('./views/nutritional-data.tmp.php', function(){


                $(this).hide();
                $(this).fadeIn("slow");

            });

            }

        });
```

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is within the scope of the success handler.

Answer (score -1):

Solved myself bby changing ajax call to:

```
            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
          url: "../ajax/add-ingredient-to-recipe.php?"+dataString,  
          dataType: "html",
          data: dataString,  

          }).done(function (){

            window.top.$.fancybox.close(true);

        });
```

and reloading the div from the parent page (in the script that opens the fancybox)

```
    $(".add-food-button").fancybox({
    width : 750,
    height : 430,
    fitToView : false,
    autoSize : false,
    transitionIn    :    'elastic',
    transitionOut    :    'elastic',
    type                : 'iframe',
    afterClose  : function() {
        $('.calorie-table').load('./views/nutritional-data.tmp.php');
        $('.calorie-table').hide();
        $('.calorie-table').fadeIn(800);
}

});
```